# Apply JQuery onclick method for elements created with Vue

Tags: vue.js, jquery-mobile

I am creating a mobile app with JQuery Mobile and trying to add some Vue script as well. So I am using Vue to add `li` elements into `ul` and have some JQuery onclick functions on those `li`s set with

`$('.newli').bind('tap',function(){});`

but for some reason its not working (nothing happening when taping on newly created `li`s, new `li`s do have correct class to be selected by JQ etc). Is there something I am missing here?  Is it better not to mix Vue with JQuery (rather rhetorical question :) ) ?

Comment: Need more code! How do you add new li? And how does your li  look after rendering?

Comment: Making Vue:      


   v_myitems=new Vue({el:'.myitemsd',     data:{items:[]}});     
   then populating items array:      
 
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){     v_myitems.items.push(result.rows.item(i)) ;        
        added li :       <li class='newli'> item1 </li>

Comment: If you don't have plans to also add Svelte for fun, the complicated React or the strange Angular to your project, I suggest you to stick to only Vue or jQuery. BTW `.bind()` is replaced with the preferred `.on()` method.